# How can I make Firefox play audio file instead of prompt me to download it?

Tags: linux, firefox, debian, debian-stretch

[This link](https://fanyi.baidu.com/gettts?lan=en&text=A%20cross%20platform%20clipboard%20operation%20library%20of%20Python&spd=3&source=web) responds an mp3 file and can download by [wget(1)](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/wget/wget.1.en.html) also that downloaded local file can play by Firefox, but Firefox can't play it use [URL](https://fanyi.baidu.com/gettts?lan=en&text=A%20cross%20platform%20clipboard%20operation%20library%20of%20Python&spd=3&source=web), instead of Firefox prompts me to download its [URL](https://fanyi.baidu.com/gettts?lan=en&text=A%20cross%20platform%20clipboard%20operation%20library%20of%20Python&spd=3&source=web).
I find out [one solution](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1152317) but not work in my case.
My `media.play-stand-alone` is `true`, I no find out any usage of `media.directshow.enabled` so I no try it.

I run on Debian Stretch, my Firefox version is `Mozilla Firefox 60.2.0`
Debian package information:

```
$ aptitude  show firefox-esr
Package: firefox-esr                     
Version: 60.2.2esr-1~deb9u1
State: installed (60.2.0esr-1~deb9u2), upgrade available (60.2.2esr-1~deb9u1)
Automatically installed: no
Priority: optional
Section: web
Maintainer: Maintainers of Mozilla-related packages <team+pkg-mozilla@tracker.debian.org>
Architecture: i386
Uncompressed Size: 173 M
Depends: libasound2 (>= 1.0.16), libatk1.0-0 (>= 1.12.4), libc6 (>= 2.18), libcairo-gobject2 (>= 1.10.0), libcairo2 (>= 1.10.0), libdbus-1-3 (>= 1.9.14), libdbus-glib-1-2 (>=
         0.78), libevent-2.0-5 (>= 2.0.10-stable), libffi6 (>= 3.0.4), libfontconfig1 (>= 2.11), libfreetype6 (>= 2.2.1), libgcc1 (>= 1:4.2), libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 (>= 2.22.0),
         libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.31.8), libgtk-3-0 (>= 3.0.0), libjsoncpp1 (>= 1.7.4), libpango-1.0-0 (>= 1.14.0), libstartup-notification0 (>= 0.8), libstdc++6 (>= 6), libvpx4 (>=
         1.6.0), libx11-6, libx11-xcb1, libxcb-shm0, libxcb1, libxcomposite1 (>= 1:0.3-1), libxdamage1 (>= 1:1.1), libxext6, libxfixes3, libxrender1, libxt6, zlib1g (>=
         1:1.2.3.4), fontconfig, procps, debianutils (>= 1.16)
Recommends: libavcodec58 | libavcodec-extra58 | libavcodec57 | libavcodec-extra57 | libavcodec56 | libavcodec-extra56 | libavcodec55 | libavcodec-extra55 | libavcodec54 |
            libavcodec-extra54 | libavcodec53 | libavcodec-extra53
Suggests: fonts-stix | otf-stix, fonts-lmodern, libgssapi-krb5-2 | libkrb53, libcanberra0, libgtk2.0-0, pulseaudio
Conflicts: iceweasel (< 45)
Breaks: xul-ext-torbutton
Provides: gnome-www-browser, www-browser
Description: Mozilla Firefox web browser - Extended Support Release (ESR)
 Firefox ESR is a powerful, extensible web browser with support for modern web application technologies.
Tags: interface::x11, role::program, uitoolkit::gtk, web::browser
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem here is that the server responds with a request header `Content-Disposition: attachment` that tells your browser to offer a download dialog instead of showing/playing the file inline.

```
$ curl -I 'https://fanyi.baidu.com/gettts?lan=en&text=A%20cross%20platform%20clipboard%20operation%20library%20of%20Python&spd=3&source=web'
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: max-age=3600
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=tts.mp3
Content-Length: 9576
Content-Type: audio/mpeg
…
```

[See the documentation for this header at MDN for more information](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition).

> In a regular HTTP response, the `Content-Disposition` response header is a header indicating if the content is expected to be displayed *inline* in the browser, that is, as a Web page or as part of a Web page, or as an *attachment*, that is downloaded and saved locally.

Now your question essentially is *How to ignore the Content-Disposition header?* [which has been previously asked on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3251575/how-to-ignore-content-disposition-attachment-in-firefox), with several recommendations, including the [Open in Browser](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/open-in-browser/) extension.

> Have you ever been annoyed when you wanted to see a document and the download popup appears which forces you to select an external application to view it?
>
> This extension allows you to open the document directly in your browser.